# Spring MVC 3 REST PUT and POST for Update and Save

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have a method in my AccountController like

```
 @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT })
    public String update(@ModelAttribute Account account) {
this.getAccountDao().save(account);
return "redirect:/users/account/";
}
```

I am using org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter and so my view has a hidden form field as -

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="account">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
....
```

Now my question is how does the controller know when to Create a new Account or to Update it or how does it know if the request is a POST or a PUT? To me it always looks like it is going to be PUT.

I just don't like using anything apart from GET and POST. The controller does not need to care whether it needs to create a new one or update it. If the form has a hidden account id field, the service can figure out what DAO method to call.

**EDIT**
If this is only going to be a PUT request then I would need to create a new jsp for POST. Unfortunately both requests are very similar in that they need almost exact data to be submitted, except for account id. I want to be able to use this same method from the controller and the same jsp for both POST and PUT and depending on either the model - account is saved or updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller doesn't know if you create or update an entity, it only knows the `RequestMethod`s which the method reacts to.

The hidden field you specified and the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` you are using, result in `PUT` being the HTTP method, visible to your controller, as the filter changes the method in the request. (according to the [javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html)).

In result, the browser uses `POST` to transmit its data to the server, then the `Filter` runs and changes the method in the request to `PUT`, so for the application behind that `Filter` it looks like the request had been sent with `PUT`.

I don't see a problem in being very similar code, just factor the similar behavoir out to another method.. eg:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST})
public String update(@ModelAttribute Account account) {
     // do POST specific things..

      // and common operations
      commonOperation();
}

@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.PUT })
public String updateWithPut(@ModelAttribute Account account) {
      // do PUT specific things...

      // and common operations
      commonOperation();
}

// code that put and post methods have in common
private void commonOperation() {
 // a lot of common code
 // that needs to be done
}
```

Comment: If this is never going to be a POST request the controller does not need "POST" verb as it is not going to be one. That would answer the first part of the question. Now I need to be able to have both POST and PUT. How do I do that with HiddenHttpMethodFilter. I can't create separate pages.

Comment: the hidden field specifies which HTTP method is visible to your application. This is a per-form-tag specific configuration, so you can send one form with POST, another with PUT, based on your needs and hidden field.

Comment: hmmm.. I will wait for more answers. I think I am doing it the correct way but not understanding a missing piece to my puzzle.

Comment: I think you need to clearify your requirment, what do you want to achieve and what is your question?

Comment: The current code should handle both POST and PUT.. well at least that's what I think it should. I need to be sure if this working or not. This does look to be the correct way of doing by not having to create separate jsp for POST or PUT. I think this is pretty clear from my question. I am going to wait for other answers to verify this.

Comment: you are asking a different question now, please clearify this in your question above. (Your old question: "Now my question is how does the controller know when to Create a new Account or to Update it or how does it know if the request is a POST or a PUT?")

Comment: updated answer, just extract common functionality to another local method. But I feel you need to be clear about, that you specify the HTTP method in the hidden field, thats it, you decide wich method should be used only once per form. You could output the hidden field conditionally.

Comment: +1 for the answer. If nobody else answers I am accepting this.